# Can I identify points in a scatter plot in RStudio and still use knitr?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am using RStudio. I want to identify points in a scatter plot and then print the plot with the identified points highlighted to a report using knitr. Here is a simple example (that doesn't work):

````
```{r,results="hide",echo=FALSE}
checked_pts <- vector(mode = "integer", length = 0)
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)
plot(x, y)
checked_pts <- identify(x, y, labels = seq_along(x), plot = FALSE)
```
# Plot with Checked Points

```{r,echo=FALSE}
plot(x,y)
points(x = x[checked_pts], y = y[checked_pts], pch = 16, col = "red")
```
````

The example prints the plot in the knitr html twice, without allowing me to identify points. Note: I have tried all of the fig.show options.

Comment: Does the point selection have to happen when you're compiling? Would it be alright to first select points, then save those points as a .csv which later get pulled into the report?

Comment: That would be ok if I have to.

Comment: So maybe run the identify function, save the points as a .csv, and then have the .Rmd read in the csv and plot those points?